Computing a complicated integral using polar coordinates not centred at the origin
This question is based on this question, which is solved by calculating the integral \begin{align}I&=\int\limits_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_{-\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{1/2}}^{\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{1/2}}\int\limits_{\sin(x+y)-2y}^{\sin(x+y)+1-x^2-y^2}{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\\&=\int\limits_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_{-\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{1/2}}^{\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{1/2}}1-x^2-y^2+2y\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\\&=2\int\limits_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_0^{\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{1/2}}2-(y-1)^2-x^2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\\&=\frac{4}{3}\int\limits_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{3/2}\,{\rm d}y\end{align}
I'm stuck with how to solve this final integral, so I thought I'd try it using cyllindrical coordinates: $$I=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_{???}^{???}r-r^3+2r^2\sin\phi\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\phi$$
However, given the centre of rotation for the cyllinder is not at the origin but at $(0,1)$, I wasn't sure what the bounds should be for $r$? Or, can I change the definition of the coordinate system slightly to take this change of centre into account?

Instead of doing this via cylindrical coordinates, try the substitution $u=y-1$ followed by $u = \sqrt{2} \sin s$, transforming the integral into:
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{4}{3}\int_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\left(2-(y-1)^2\right)^{3/2} dy \\
=\frac{4}{3} \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \left( 2-u^2 \right)^\frac{3}{2} du\\
= \frac{4}{3} \int_{\frac{- \pi}{2}}^{\frac{ \pi}{2}}\left( 2-2 \sin^2(s)\right)^\frac{3}{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} \cos(s) {\rm d}s \\
= \frac{16}{3} \int_{\frac{- \pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^4(s) {\rm d}s = 
\end{equation} \frac{16}{3} \int_{\frac{- \pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^3(s) \cdot \cos(s) {\rm d}s \\$$
The last integral is easy to do by integration by parts.

Nice, thanks! The first substitution is pretty obvious - however what led you to know that the second substitution would be appropriate?

Whenever I see $\alpha - x^2$ in an integral, I usually try substituting $x= \sqrt{\alpha} \sin u$, as then that expression simplifies to $\alpha \cos^2 u$, which sometimes leads to cancellation. Of course, this doesn't work a lot of times, but in this case, it worked because I noticed that my substitution transforms the $dx$ into a cosine term, which motivated me to try the substitution out

I've since figured out the answer to this. Using the expression for the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2-2=0$ we can derive the polar equation $r=\sin\phi+\sqrt{2-\cos^2\phi}$ for $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$. So the $r$ bounds go from $0$ to this function of $\phi$ and the integral is \begin{align}I&=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{\sin\phi+\sqrt{2-\cos^2\phi}}r-r^3+2r^2\sin\phi\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\phi\\&=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\phi+\sqrt{2-\cos^2\phi}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left(\sin\phi+\sqrt{2-\cos^2\phi}\right)^4+\frac{2}{3}\left(\sin\phi+\sqrt{2-\cos^2\phi}\right)^3\sin\phi\,{\rm d}\phi\\&=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{5}{12}\sin^4\phi-\frac{1}{4}\cos^4\phi+\frac{3}{2}\sin^2\phi+\frac{1}{2}\cos^2\phi-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\phi\cos^2\phi+\frac{\sin\phi}{3}\left[1+3\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi\right]\sqrt{2-\cos^2\phi}\,{\rm d}\phi\end{align}
Still no easier to compute!
